# Error parsing yml configuration for fos_rest bundle in Symfony 3

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.2, symfony-3.3

i am configuring the fosrest bundle in symfony 3. But i'm gettin this error:

**While scanning a flow node we had this expected the node content, but found org.jvyamlb.tokens.PositionedKeyToken**

My block code is as follows:

```
fos_rest:
    format_listener:
        enabled: true
        rules:
            - { path: '^/api', priorities: ['html', 'json', 'xml'], fallback_format: ~, prefer_extension: true }
```

The error is shown in this line:

```
  - { path: '^/api', priorities: ['html', 'json', 'xml'], fallback_format: ~, prefer_extension: true }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That error message appears to related to a [Java-based Yaml parsing library](https://github.com/olabini/jvyamlb/blob/master/src/main/org/jvyamlb/tokens/PositionedKeyToken.java).

Are you including any yaml/yml files within your app/config or bundle configuration from outside the PHP source?

You may also find that running `bin/console lint:yaml src` (and with `lint:yaml app`) might show some more clarity on the subject. Also searching your codebase for `PositionedKeyToken`.

Comment: Thank you @alister_b. Yes i just change the order of the parameters and it works. I left the array priorities in the end like this: - { path: '^/api', fallback_format: json , prefer_extension: true, priorities: ['html', 'json', 'xml'] }